# Add a space between the axis and text with NVD3 charts

Tags: css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I tried to understand which classes were involved in the style for the axis but It didn't help me at all.

I didn't find the right class to add a margin between the axis and the text.

Could you suggest me something about it ?

Comment: you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501959/how-to-add-space-between-axis-and-line-in-d3-line-chart

Comment: I tried to follow it but I can't understand how it can help me with nvd3 library.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926328/giving-axis-ticks-more-space-in-nvd3

Comment: @knives22 it is only helpful to add the margin for the chart. I want to add a space between the axis and the text used for every tick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you can select the axis text and change x, y, dx, dy, text-anchor attributes accordingly, for example:

```
 d3.select(".nv-x").selectAll(".tick text")
    .attr('y', 15);
```